# How to hide the radio button dot in a buttonset widget using jQuery-UI?

Tags: jquery-ui

For a long time, a web site that I maintain had been using jQuery-UI v1.11.2.  I decided to  upgrade to the latest version which is currently v1.12.1.  After the upgrade, I noticed that my jquery-ui buttonsets (which are basically radio buttons) now have the little dot showing.  Previously that dot wasn't there.

I went over to the official [jQuery-UI help docs for buttonsets](https://api.jqueryui.com/buttonset/).  It turns out that their example now has those dots.  I guess that's the new look.

[image]

Well, I want the old look back.  No dots.

How do I made those dots disappear?

Comment: Are you using Smoothness exclusively as the Stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

> This widget is deprecated, use Controlgroup instead.

Suggest making use of `classes`.

> Specify additional classes to add to the widget's elements. Any of classes specified in the Theming section can be used as keys to override their value. To learn more about this option, check out the learn article about the classes option.

This gives you the ability to more directly modify the CSS of an element inside a widget. The "dot" is made by changing the background color of the `span` and then giving it a border to make the "dot" smaller.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#radio").controlgroup({
    classes: {
      "ui-controlgroup": "nodot"
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div.nodot label.ui-checkboxradio-checked .ui-icon-background {
  border: 0 solid #aaaaaa;
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Favorite jQuery Project</legend>
    <div id="radio">
      <input type="radio" id="sizzle" name="project">
      <label for="sizzle">Sizzle</label>
      <input type="radio" id="qunit" name="project" checked="checked">
      <label for="qunit">QUnit</label>
      <input type="radio" id="color" name="project">
      <label for="color">Color</label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

There is still a hover effect being applied, that is adding a `box-shadow` that I couldn't find.